# RESTful API - Get last of an element

Tags: rest, api

What's the best practice for getting the last added element (let's say we know that because of a created_at field on the resource).

Should it be a call to the get all with max results on 1 like:

```
GET ../rest/v1/article?page=0&size=1&order=created_at,desc
```

and will return an array of one element

or maybe an "special" call like:

```
GET ../rest/v1/article/last
```

and will return an element.

I am looking for a best practice if there's one pattern for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a RESTful expert, but in my opinion the first solution seems the best.

The second is more practical, but routes are often associated with resources, the addition of a "last", especially preceded by a "/" seems strange to me.

In addition, API users usually use the sorting parameters, and what about users which need 10 last elements ?

If you add something after `../rest/v1/article`, it must be an ID for one particular element, a sub-resource, or for actions that are outside the CRUD like `../rest/v1/article/:id/subscription`.

Comment: I complement this answer. I'd also opt for the parameter option. When you draw a slash at the end of a resource name, you should also be aware you are designing a new resource. A resource is a *thing* and this makes the pair with nouns not verbs nor adjectives. This can be used as a nice rule of thumb when you are in doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Both URLs are RESTful and identify a Resource. Of course the first would return a collection containing a single element while the second would return this element directly.

The **first form** will be automatically supported if you support paging and sorting at all.

You write

> or maybe an "special" call

I don't see this as an 'or', it should be an 'and'. The **second form** is **optional** and it could be helpful. If you have an URL pattern like

```
GET ../rest/v1/article/{id}
```

it is easy to implement logic that can distinguish normal IDs like, for example, `123` or `A567` from special IDs like 'last`.